# Node.js does not wait for the data

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function checkContact(req, res) {
    for (var numb in req.body) {

        console.log(numb + ":" + req.body[numb]);

        checkValue(numb, function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log(result);
                send[result] = "true";
                console.log(send);

            }
            if (err) {
                console.log(err + "not");
            }
        });
    }

    res.json(send);

}

function checkValue(number, callback) {

    mongo.connect(conn, function() {

        var doc = mongo.collection("user");
        doc.findOne({
            number: number
        }, function(err, res) {
            if (res) {

                //console.log(send+"val");
                //send[number]="true";
                callback(null, number);

            }

        });
        callback(null, 0);
    });

}
```

Here `res.json(send)` is executed immediately, without waiting for the data to be put in send variable. I am aware that node.js is asynchronous and that is how it executes. Is there a way I can send the response only after the for loop has finished executing? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `res.json(send)` is called right after the for loop, when the async tasks haven't been finished yet. You should call `res.json(send)` inside your callback (when you get all the data). Try using something like `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

Because Node.JS is asynchronous, you need to embed this in the callback.

```
function checkContact(req, res) {
    var reqLength = req.body.length;

    for (var numb in req.body) {

        console.log(numb + ":" + req.body[numb]);

        checkValue(numb, function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log(result);
                send[result] = "true";
                console.log(send);

            }
            if (err) {
                console.log(err + "not");
            }

            reqLength--;

            if(reqLength === 0) {
                res.json(send);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs uses async call you should try `Promises` for waiting and sending response
read this article it will help you

[http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/][1]